# SQL exceptions don't appear to be working

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Anyone know why my exceptions aren't working? When i test the sql the only exception that appears is the when others.

This is my first stored procedure, i want it to insert new students using parameter values.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_STUDENT_TO_DB (pSTUid number, pSTUname varchar2) AS
    Out_Of_Range Exception;
    BEGIN 
    IF pSTUid <=1 AND pSTUid >=499 THEN
    RAISE Out_Of_Range;
END IF;
INSERT INTO STUDENT (STUid, STUname)
VALUES (pSTUid, pSTUname);

EXCEPTION
WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_iNDEX THEN
dbms_output.put_line('-20010.   Duplicate student ID');

WHEN Out_Of_Range THEN
dbms_output.put_line('-20002.   student ID  out of  range');

WHEN OTHERS THEN 
dbms_output.put_line('-20000. Error');
END;
```

This is my second stored procedure, i want this to call my first sp.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_STUDENT_VIASQLDEV (pSTUid number, pSTUname varchar2) AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO STUDENT (STUid, STUname)
VALUES (pSTUid, pSTUname);

dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------------------');
dbms_output.put_line('Adding student ID: ' || pSTUid || ' Name: ' || pSTUname);

EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN 
dbms_output.put_line('-20000. Error');
END;
```

Comment: This is basically the same problem as the question you posted yesterday. Your procedure `ADD_STUDENT_VIASQLDEV` doesn't call `ADD_STUDENT_TO_DB` so why on earth would you expect exceptions declared in the first procedure to be be raised by running the second procedure?

Comment: _"This is my second stored procedure, i want this to call my first sp."_ So call it. What does that have to do with your question about exceptions? Also, you will find a little code formatting will make it much easier to visualise what the procedure is doing.

Comment: It's another logic problem. Look at your condition. You have used a Boolean AND. But an `id` cannot be less than one *and* greater than 499 at the same time. Try an OR instead.

Answer (score 0):

there should exist `IF pSTUid <=1 OR pSTUid >=499 THEN` instead of your statement for out_of_range